# Checking Sign-in Status for Each ViewController

Tags: swift, google-signin, firebase-security

I am a beginner. I am developing an app with swift. I am using Firebase for signin. But I was wondering if I need to write codes to check user's sign-in status for each viewController for security. Or sign-in is needed only for the sign-in viewController like locking just a front door. My code may not be needed but below is the code that I wrote:

```
        // Mark: User Sign-in Status Recheck
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if user != nil {
                if let user = user {
                    let userUid = user.uid
                    let userEmail = user.email
                }
            } else {
                let InitialSignInFirstViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInFirstViewController") as! InitialSignInViewController
                self.present(SignInFirstViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have a swift page that checks if the user is signed in when the app loads. If they are signed in they continue to the app, and you don't need to check until the app quits, and opens again. If they aren't signed in they go to another view controller to get signed in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You just had a page checking singin status. After user signed in on the page, you don't check signin status because there is no way for user to access to the pages shown after signin, right? Is is safe from hacking?

Comment: It’s safe as long as the person doesn’t get another persons passwords or other credentials. If your concerned about hacking maybe look into two factor authentication for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manage the state or run the listener, there is more simpler way to do that, i.e.,

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  // User is signed in.
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  // ...
}
```

> Update

You can create one class which just provide the user sign in status like below:

```
struct UserSignInStatus {
    var isLoggedIn: Bool {
        return (Auth.auth().currentUser != nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage:** `UserSignInStatus.isLoggedIn`

You can put this code any where like in your `AppDelegate` class where you check the signin status and depending on that managing your `rootViewController`. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just one more question here. If I put the code in the AppDelegate, It would check signin status when a page is called and if user is not singned in it will show user a singup page. This is what I want but there are three pages (e.g., sign up and find password pages), which user can't have signin status. If I put the code in the AppDelegate, user can't stay with sign up and find password pages (i guess). How can I deal with it? Thanks again :)

Comment: Will do. I really appreciate it!